# Doctrine2 select birthday range

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all employees who have their birthday the upcoming 5 days. The birthday is saved in a date field. It feels like I have to use a between, but then the year range ruins the result.

Basically I want to select a date by month and day only, in a range of 5 days.

Database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_office_employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstname` varchar(256) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `surname` varchar(256) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(256) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Does anybody know a single query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this in MySQL (**edited** - REALLY WORKING EXAMPLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_office_employee` e 
WHERE FLOOR(
        (
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
                CONCAT(
                    YEAR(CURDATE()) + (DATE_FORMAT(e.birthdate, '%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d')),
                    DATE_FORMAT(e.birthdate, '-%m-%d'))) 
            - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()))
        / 86400) < 5
```

---

<strike>*SQL query written below doesn't select birthday which are next year (i.e. on 1-5th Jan, when it's 31st Dec), so use one above...*</strike>

> SELECT * FROM `tbl_office_employee` e WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(e.birthdate, CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-%m-%d')))  BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))

<strike>*I had to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, because of day changes i.e from 31st May to 5th June (5 isnt't greater than 31) and change year in `e.birthdate`.*</strike>

---

It can be done in DQL (Doctrine 1):

```php
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('e.firtsname')
    ->from('tbl_office_employee e')
    ->where('e.date BETWEEN ? AND ?', array($today_date, $date_plus_5_days))
    ->getSqlQuery();
```

which should output basically the same.

I don't think `DATE_ADD` is availible in DQL out of the box, but [there is chapter called *DQL User Defined Functions* in docs, which has example implementation of `DATE_ADD` function for MySQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#date-add).

Comment: This only selects the records of this year. I need the result of all years. The question is about birthdays. BTW, thanx for the Doctrine example, but I use Doctrine 2.

Comment: Edited answer, so it doesn't check year (sure, birthdays are each year ;)).

Comment: Check my answer once again - I've tested it and it turned out that it doesn't work if birthday is next year (i.e. on 1-5th Jan, when it's 31st Dec now).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m%d') between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') and date_format(adddate(now(), interval 4 day),'%m%d');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), '%m%d') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`birthdate`, '%m%d') ASC;
```

or

```
SELECT   * FROM member WHERE   (1 =   (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL   4 DAY),birthdate) / 365.25)) -(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),birthdate)   / 365.25))) ORDER BY MONTH(birthdate),DAY(birthdate)
```

All query's are tested.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I haven't tested it, but can give a try...

```
SELECT *, 
CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY AS coming_date,
CURRENT_DATE() AS today_date
FROM tbl_office_employee
WHERE birthdate <= coming_date AND birthdate >= today_date
```

Comment: This does not take in account that I don't want to take the year in the select. Since I want to select birthdays it should be independent of the year.